# How to customize the appearance of plots in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Recently, I am trying to practice something new with using Shinny application in R and I am having a serious difficulty to customize the layout for the 2 plots, actually one table and one plot. I am not able to share the whole data I am using but I think, one can find out the problem easily and point out a solution as this is most probably not a difficult question.

```
# Load required packages
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(shinythemes)
library(sf) 
library(rnaturalearth) 
library(ggthemes)
library(tidyverse)

# Define data

data1 <- data.frame("A" =  rep(1:11, each = 9),
                    "B" =  rep(c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z"), times = 11),
                    "C" =  rep(c("d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f"), times = 11),
                    "value" = 1:99)


# Define UI
ui <- navbarPage("",
                 includeCSS("~/www/dark_mode.css"),
                 tabPanel("<zx<x<sxsad",
                          titlePanel(h1("")),
                          sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput("A", "A:", choices = unique(data1$A)),
                                                     selectInput("B", "B:", choices = unique(data1$B))),
                                        mainPanel(h2("asdasdasda", align = "center"),
                                                  p("lşdnasşdkjfnasşkjdfbsaşkdjf", 
                                                    style = "font-family: 'cambria'; font-si75pt"),
                                                  p("Wow, that's so cool!!!"),
                                                  gt_output(outputId = "my_gt_table"),
                                                  plotOutput("plot")))),
                 tabPanel("AAA",
                          titlePanel(h1("asdasdasdsad"))),
                 tabPanel("AAA",
                          titlePanel(h1("sdfsadfsafdsadfs"))))

              
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_gt_table <-
    render_gt(data1 %>%
                filter(A == input$A, B == input$B) %>%
                # CONVERT TO A {gt} TABLE! VERY IMPORTANT STEP!
                gt() %>%
                summary_rows(columns = c(value),
                             fns = list(Toplam = ~sum(.)),
                             formatter = fmt_number,
                             use_seps = FALSE) %>%
                gt_theme_espn())
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = data1 %>% filter(A == input$A), aes(x = A, y = value)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
  }, width = 100, height = 100)
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

which results with this

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to align the table and plot horizontally. How can I do that with fluidRow or is there any other solution?

Comment: Well, you are right, we don't need your whole data. But to help you it would be helpful if you share a minimal working code or app. As is you are expecting us to create a minimal reproducible example and add all the missing pieces.

Comment: Just provided a detailed question with the fake data and the whole code. I hope that it helps. Thanks for your help beforehand.